# 1098-T with scholarship listed this year 2018 as "billed" but tuition was reported on 2017 year's 1098-T as "paid"

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, school

This is very confusing.  I'm required to report the Tuition and Scholarship from my 1098-T.  I paid the full year's tuition in 2017 (fall and spring 2018) so no Tuition was *billed* for 2018 (well actually a small lab fee of $50).  But the school has Scholarship "income" split, half was on the 1098-T for 2017 (far less than the tuition paid), now the other half is on the 1098-T as "billed" to 2018. With no offsetting "billed" tuition, because it was already paid!

The scholarship in total was well below full tuition, so I got the benefit of it and paid less in tuition in 2017 - no cash benefit was ever received.  But how do I report this?  The 1098-T if entered verbatim would have me taxed on it as income.  The benefit was actually "received" and used the previous year.

Should I ask the school to amend the 1098-T forms?  I have no idea what direction to go on this.  Certainly don't think taxing it is proper, if this amount were on the previous 1098-T the paid tuition would still have been greater than the scholarship amount, and no tax liability would be found.

Suggestions?

Comment: You keep using the word *billed*, but I do not think it means what you think it means.  What numbers are in what boxes on the 1098-T?

Comment: Two questions: Is box 3 checked on the 1098-T? "Check if you have changed your reporting method for 2018"  Was box 7 checked last year year? "Check this box if the  amount in box 1  includes amounts for an academic period beginning January—March 2018"

Comment: Box 3 was checked as a matter of fact.  So I think I have a solution.  In Turbo Tax checked the box that a 1098-T was received, but then No, I don't want to try to reduce my taxes with education expenses.  No more questions asked.